# im getting error like "Tables cannot have more than 0 materialized views, failed to create materialized view"

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql, datastax-astra

this is the command I used for creating a table in Cassandra.

```
create table materialed_main (car_make text,car_model text,id int,department text,frist text, last text,primary key(car_make,car_model,id));
```

and this is a materialized view for the above table.

```
create materialized view materialed_view as select * from materialed_main where first is not null and car_make is not null and car_model is not null and id is not null primary key(first,car_make,car_model, id);
```

but I'm not sure why I'm getting this error

```
Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Tables cannot have more than 0 materialized views, failed to create materialized view materialed_view on table materialed_main"
```

Comment: what cassandra version? have you enabled materialized views ?

Comment: Thank you @AlexOtt for helping out, I just got to know I should enable materialized views. But how can I enable it in something like Datastax AstraDB, because I think it doesn't have the configuration file to make changes.

Comment: Ah, it’s Astra. I think that message says that you can’t have MV on it…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-cql/doc/cql/cql_using/useOverviewMV.html):

> Note: Materialized views are not available on Astra serverless databases. For more, see [Astra database limits](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra/docs/datastax-astra-database-limits.html#_tables)

That second page says:

> Secondary indexes and materialized views are not available for serverless databases. Our team is working to offer materialized views for serverless databases soon

Answer (score 0):

Use CUSTOM INDEX instead of MATERIALIZED VIEW.
[Storage-Attached Indexing (SAI)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra/docs/using-storage-attached-indexing-sai.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30478436)